# How to filter and find out all the columns of a certain data type in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let I've a dataframe **df**

```
 Name     Age       Job
 
 Rick     24      Worker
 Max      20      Worker
 Sam      48      Driver
 
 Expected output:  
                  Name
                  Job
```

Now, I want to print out those column(name) which has **object** type data.
Here, Is my attempt:

```
for column in df:
    if df.dtypes(column) == 'object':
        print(column)
```

But I'm getting an error which is:
*" if df.dtypes(column) == 'object':
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable "*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) as follows:

```
df.select_dtypes('object').columns.to_list()
```

Output:

```
['Name', 'Job']
```

Or:

```
for column in df:
    if df[column].dtype == 'object':
        print(column)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[x for x in df.columns if df[x].dtype == object]
```

Output:

```
['Name', 'Job']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df.columns[df.dtypes == object].to_list()
```

which gives

```
>> ['Name', 'Job']
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the for loop. Try:

```
for column in df.columns:
    if type(column) == 'object':
        print(column)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try:

code:

```
df.dtypes[df.dtypes == 'object'].index.values
```

Prints:

```
array(['Name', 'Job'], dtype=object)
```

For printing out the columns itself:

```
[print(val) for val in df.dtypes[df.dtypes == 'object'].index]
Name
Job
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
[print(col) for col in df.select_dtypes(include = object).columns]
Name
Job
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
# Get columns whose data type is object
filteredColumns = df.dtypes[df.dtypes == np.object]
# List of columns whose data type is object
listOfColumnNames = list(filteredColumns.index)
print(listOfColumnNames)
```

Output:

['Name', 'Job']